# Write a C code that will print out the following pattern using nested for loops

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, nested

I am not getting the output that I am looking for. Could someone help me with spotting the problem? The output that I am supposed to get is:

```
OXXX
XOXX
XXOX
XXXO
```

My code is:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
    int i;
    int j;
    int counter_1= 0;
    int counter_2= 0;
    for (i=0;i<4;i++) {
      for (j=0;j<4;j++) {
        if (counter_1==counter_2) {
          printf("O");
        } else {
          printf("X");
        } 
        counter_2++;
      }
      counter_1++;
      printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is a piece of coursework? I can't see why you're asking about this otherwise ...

Comment: how is this relevant to my question?

Comment: the problem is very simple, the solution must be very simple too, look my answer and you will understand

Answer (score 1):

Out of wrong why searching for something so complicated ? The initial cause of your bug is the complexity of your solution.

The goal is to draw a diagonal, from the definition of the diagonal when the column number and the line number are equal put a O else a X :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  unsigned line, column;
  const unsigned size = 4; /* any square size you want */

  for (line = 0; line < size; ++line) {
    for (column = 0; column < size; ++column) {
      putchar((column == line) ? 'O' : 'X');
    }
    putchar('\n');
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall -g c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
OXXX
XOXX
XXOX
XXXO
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to reset `counter_2` back to `0` after each inner loop completes and also, if you want the patterns to be on the same line, replace the `printf("\n");` with `printf(" ");`

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
    int i;
    int j;
    int counter_1= 0;
    int counter_2= 0;
    for (i=0;i<4;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<4;j++) {
            if (counter_1==counter_2) {
                printf("O");
            } else {
                printf("X");
            } 
            counter_2++;
        }
        counter_1++;
        counter_2 = 0; // Reset counter back to 0
        printf(" ");   // Print space between each pattern
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I was thinking about the same problem, I thought it would reset automatically since it exits the inner loop, thank you again.

Comment: why something so complicated with all these variables ? out of that you produce all on one line, which is not the expected behavior